# How can I make a drop down menu without changing the width of the main menu item?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I am new to HTML and CSS.

I am trying to make a navigation bar with a drop down menu.

I created navbar. But the width of the main menu item is changing with the sub menu Item.

How can I stop changing the width of the main Menu Item. 
here main menu item is "SCHOOLING".

I don't want to change the width of SCHOOLING.

**Before change**

[image]

**After change**

[image]

html code for NavBar

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Navigation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nav.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navbar" class="bold">
        <ul>
            <li style="border-top-left-radius:10px;border-bottom-left-radius:10px;"><a href="index.html"  style="padding-left:21px;">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="subject.html" >SCHOOLING</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">HIGH SCHOOL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HIGHER SECONDARY</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="subject.html">ENGINEERING</a></li>
            <li><a href="subject.html">UG | PG</a></li>
            <li><a href="subject.html">SPECIAL CLASSES</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li style="border-right:none;"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS code For the NavBar

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Courier New, monospace;
    }

.fleft {
    float: left;
   }
.fright {
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
    }

.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
    }

/* NAV BAR */

#navbar {
   background-color: #333; 
    margin:10px;
    height: 40px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
} 

#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}

#navbar ul li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #dede0e;
    font-size: 1.5em;

}
#navbar ul li a {
    color: white;
        display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
        padding: 6px 10px;

}
#navbar ul li:hover {
        background-color: #000000;


}

/* DROP DOWN MENU */

#navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;

    color: blueviolet;
    background: #a80000;

}
#navbar ul ul li {
    float: none;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
#navbar ul ul li a {
    border-right: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
#navbar ul li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the position of the dropdown menu to absolute.

```
#navbar ul ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    color: blueviolet;
    background: #a80000;
    position: absolute;
}
```